# Novel with a scene where a mother is compelled to pile blankets on her newborn

Tags: story-identification, novel, magic, mind-control

I have a newborn son who's having a harder time with thermoregulation, and it made me flash back to a book, a fantasy novel I think, where a character finds his wife sleepwalking and piling more and more blankets on the baby, mumbling that they're cold, or maybe that they need to be hidden, but risking making them too hot, or even suffocating. I remember it as being magic, done by an enemy. The target might have been nobility of some sort.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Guardians of the West** by David Eddings has such a scene. Ce'Nedra is mind-controlled by an unknown baddie into piling blankets onto her newborn son.

> Garion looked through the doorway. Ce'Nedra was standing by the cradle in her white nightdress, her eyes vacant and staring, with another figure beside her. On the chair at the foot of the cradle was a great heap of blankets and pillows. Dreamily, the Rivan Queen was methodically piling the bedclothes on top of her baby.

...

> 'I have to hide him', Ce'Nedra replied stubbornly. 'They want to kill him.'

...

> 'But how can I protect Geran from his own mother? I mean - if this man can come to Ce'Nedra in her sleep like that and make her do things, how can I possibly-?'

Comment: Thank you. That was bugging me. I can place it now.

Comment: No worries. I remember thinking all sorts of weird stuff that bugged me when I was doing the night shifts with my newborns. Hope he sorts out the temperature control soon!